# Load content from file as argument in ant

Tags: ant

Assume I have a file test.key and the file contains a string let call “123456789”.
How can I pass this file as an argument to a program in ant build?
I wonder if Something like this is possible?
ant -Darg=‘cat test.key’

Where cat test.key is a command on Linux terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LoadFile ant task, which reads the content of a file into a property: 
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html

```
<loadfile property="arg.value"
      srcFile="test.key"
      failonerror="false"/>
```

You can then use this property in an exec task with this property:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

```
<exec executable="myprogram">
  <arg value="${arg.value}"/>
</exec>
```

To add some more flexibility, you can pass the file name as a property:

```
ant -Dfile.name=test.key
```

So the LoadFile task the becomes:

```
    <loadfile property="arg.value"
      srcFile="${file.name}"
      failonerror="false"/>
```